# Find the target of an alias or link in Quicksilver

Tags: symlink, alias, quicksilver

Can I find the target of an alias or symbolic link using Quicksilver? I don't find a way to do so on [this Quicksilver reference](http://mysite.verizon.net/hmelman/QSRef.pdf) which is the best source I know of at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn’t aware of a way, but with some trial and error, I found that hitting `→` or `/` will take you to the original item for symbolic links. It doesn’t seem to work for aliases. There should probably be a “Show Original” action.

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately this isn't working for me for either links or aliases.

Comment: Which version are you running? I tested with the latest release (1.1.3) and with my custom build.

Comment: Oops--my mistake. When I tested I selected a symlink and then used Cmd-Esc to get into Quicksilver. It turns out that doing that already dereferences the symbolic link; I got the original file in Quicksilver to begin with. So when I pressed / or → nothing happened, and all I was looking for was something to change. FWIW I'm also using the latest release (1.1.3).